# ¿Cómo llamar o crear un hilo de un archivo con playsound importado?

Tags: python, hilos

continuando con el aprendizaje de python y las pruebas y errores... orientarme como hacer el start de un hilo de un archivo importado.

`sonido.py`

```
from playsound import playsound
import threading

    class ruido (threading.Thread):
        def eco(sonido):
            directorio = 'D:\\sors\\Sonidos\\'
            if sonido == 'bien':
                melodia = directorio + 'mario-bros.mp3'
            if sonido == 'mal':
                melodia = directorio + 'pacman-dies.mp3'
            if sonido == 'botes-bien':
                melodia = directorio + 'R2D2.mp3'
            if sonido == 'aplausos':
                melodia = directorio + 'applause.wav'
            #playsound (melodia,block=False)
    
            eco = threading.Thread(target=playsound,args=(melodia,))
    
            #tocata = eco(playsound (melodia,block=False))
```

`principal.py`

```
from threading import Thread
import threading
from urllib.request import urlopen
from playsound import playsound
from normalizar_equipos import normalizar
from sonidos import ruido
......
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Idioma "es-ES" (código para el español de España)
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf-8')
    ##### * DEFINO LOS HILOS DE LOS SONIDOS ************                    
    bien = ruido ('bien')
```

***Se produjo una excepción: AssertionError
group argument must be None for now
File "D:\Sorteos\python\sors\principal.py", line 4003, in 
bien = ruido ('bien')***

```
bien.start()
mal = eco ('mal')
mal.start()
botesbien = eco ('botes-bien')
botesbien.start()
```

Estará todo mal porque he estado haciendo pruebas, creyendo que ya entiendo el concepto de los hilos pero, veo que todavía estoy bastante lejos.

Los .start, están a lo largo del programa principal, creo que no es necesario que los ponga aquí.

Desconozco si esta bien definida la clase ruido para usarla como un thread, y como tendria que utilizar en principal.py.

Gracias anticipadas.-

Comment: No veo que uses start en ningun lado. Si ese no es el problema, podrias mostrarnos un codigo donde falle el uso de start por favor?

Comment: Tienes que mostrar un código que sea llegar y copiar, para poder probarlo en nuestros equipos. Así como está, cualquier respuesta será pura especulación basada en datos insuficientes.

Answer (score 0):

Éste es el código que necesitaba para que funcionase.

```
sonidos.py

from playsound import playsound
import threading

class ruido (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,sonido):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sonido = sonido
    def run (self):
        directorio = 'D:\\Sors\\Sonidos\\'
        if self.sonido == 'bien':
            melodia = directorio + 'mario-bros.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'mal':
            melodia = directorio + 'pacman-dies.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'botes-bien':
            melodia = directorio + 'R2D2.mp3'
        if self.sonido == 'aplausos':
            melodia = directorio + 'applause.wav'
        playsound (melodia,block=False)
        #eco = threading.Thread(target=playsound,args=(melodia,))
        #tocata = eco(playsound (melodia,block=False))
```

principal.py

```
##### * DEFINO LOS HILOS DE LOS SONIDOS ************    
aplauso = ruido('aplausos')
aplauso.START()
bien = ruido ('bien')
bien.START()
mal = ruido ('mal')
mal.START()
botesbien = ruido ('botes-bien')
botesbien.START()
```

Gracias.